# Javascript calculate time between two DateTimes. Including only working hours

Tags: javascript, laravel, momentjs

What I've done.
Used Moment.js to calculate the difference in minutes. This was without excluding weekends and non-working hours.

Downloaded a Moment.js plugin (Moment-business) which has the exact function I'm looking for, but needs a tremendous amount of calculation time.

This is expected as the dates can differ in two days to two-hundred days.

My 'solution'.
Iterate from the start date to the end date in raw minutes. while not counting the minutes outside of my boundaries. As you can imagine, this is very resource intensive. (150 objects, all need calculations, every 30 seconds, over long periods of time).

My idea for a better solution.
Once my counter hits a minute past my end-working hour, add 16 hours in raw minutes so it skips 16 hours worth of looping. Same with weekdays.

I feel as if this will be slow as well, especially considering I've been using my original method in C# and it was extremely fast. And it still has an O(1) notation.

My question is.
Is there a way to efficiently calculate the time between two DateTimes in javascript? (I'm also using Laravel for what it's worth.)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question seems too vague for us to be of value. You should post code if you want help.

Comment: Are you handling on blade or pure javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop through the minutes from the first date to the second date... The difference between the dates should be a non-factor for the amount of time it will take to compute the difference. Just do math. Here is some pseudocode:

calcDifference(a, b)

1. Calculate remaining business time on the day of Date a
2. Calculate the weeks of Date b - Date a, multiple by number of working days per week and working hours per day
3. Calculate business time already passed on the day of Date b
4. Add together (1), (2), and (3)

No plugins needed.